# In-text citation with biblatex-apa not using et al. correctly? Two authors listed before et al

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style

I'm writing my thesis, and have had the strangest behavior from just one in-text citation. I'm using biblatex/biber with the following setup:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt, twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, 
            language=american, 
            backend=biber, 
            natbib=true, 
            hyperref=true, 
            uniquelist=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
```

I had been using `bibtex`/`natbib` earlier, hence the `natbib=true`, but swapped out all the `\citep` and `\citet` references for `\parencite` and `\textcite`.

The issue is with this entry:

```
@article{nowak2014,
    title={Tree and forest effects on air quality and human health in the {United States}},
    author={Nowak, David J. and Hirabayashi, Satoshi and Bodine, Allison and Greenfield, Eric},
    journaltitle={Environmental Pollution},
    volume={193},
    pages={119--129},
    year={2014},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

This is the only work I have for Nowak in 2014. As you can see it has five authors, so, according to my best understanding of APA style, the first reference should list all authors and subsequent references should just list (Nowak, et al., 2014) or Nowak, et al. (2014).

But that is not what I get:

```
\parencite{nowak2014} yields (Nowak, Hirabayashi, Bodine, & Greenfield, 2014), but then

\parencite{nowak2014} subsequently yields (Nowak, Hirabayashi, et al., 2014), and

\textcite{nowak2014} yields Nowak, Hirabayashi, et al. (2014)
```

According to all the APA references I can find ([for example](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/3/)), this is not the correct behavior. Is there something wrong with my setup or with my understanding of APA? All my references work correctly except this one. What's different?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

The code you've posted, made into an MWE, does not produce the issue you are describing.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt, twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,
            language=american,
            backend=biber,
            natbib=true,
            hyperref=true,
            uniquelist=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{nowak2014,
    title={Tree and forest effects on air quality and human health in the {United States}},
    author={Nowak, David J. and Hirabayashi, Satoshi and Bodine, Allison and Greenfield, Eric},
    journaltitle={Environmental Pollution},
    volume={193},
    pages={119--129},
    year={2014},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{nowak2014}

\parencite{nowak2014}

\textcite{nowak2014} 

\end{document}
```

[image: non-problem]

I am guessing that you have another entry where the first author is Nowak, the year is 2014 and there are other author(s). If so, `uniquelist=true` is responsible for the behaviour as it causes `biblatex` to ensure that labels uniquely identify bibliography entries. Without that, it would not be clear *which* Nowak et al. (2014) you had in mind. (Did you mean Nowak, Smith and Jones (2014) or did you mean Nowak, Hook and Waverly (2014)?)

However, without a proper example i.e. code we can use to reproduce the problem you are seeing, this must remain no more than a guess.

Comment: As I said, there is no other entry with Nowak from 2014. I've been playing around with adding in one Nowak entry at a time (I have four others from between 1994 and 2000), and it looks like any time I add a Nowak paper with more than two authors, regardless of year, the undesired behavior occurs. If I set `uniquelist=false`, then it appears to fix the issue, though this seems odd. Doesn't uniquelist use the minimum number of names necessary to disambiguate up to the number set by `maxnames`? Since one author and the year is enough to disambiguate in this case, why do I see this behavior?

Comment: @tirefire That seems odd.... I would think the same as you.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the citation author list to be unique within the same year, then you want [`uniquelist=minyear`](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#page=69):

> Disambiguate the `labelname` list only if the truncated list is identical to another one with the same `labelyear`. This mode of operation is useful for author-year styles and requires `labeldateparts=true`.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered exactly the same problem. But in my case there were two entries for the same first author and the same year in my .bib file. One was labelled Huang2014 (i.e. @article{Huang2014,), and the other Huang2014a. Both had '2014' for the year. When I changed the year entry for the second one to '2014a' (i.e. year = {2014a}) it fixed the problem.