# biblatex-apa not using et al. correctly for in-text citations

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I have checked for duplicates to this question, but since the output from the solutions has changed for some, and my problem is not solved, I am asking again.

My problem is that as far as I have understood the APA style guide, the first citation should include up to 6 authors, but the second time this citation is called, it should only insert firstAuthor et al. instead of up to all six.

Why is the default behavior of biblatex-apa to not do this? Below is a workable example that shows that the output already starts with the et al.

```
\documentclass[english,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{allemang.etal_2020,
  title = {Semantic {{Web}} for the {{Working Ontologist}}: {{Effective Modeling}} for {{Linked Data}}, {{RDFS}}, and {{OWL}}},
  shorttitle = {Semantic {{Web}} for the {{Working Ontologist}}},
  author = {Allemang, Dean and Hendler, Jim and Gandon, Fabien},
  date = {2020},
  edition = {3},
  volume = {33},
  publisher = {{Association for Computing Machinery}},
  location = {{New York, NY, USA}},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{allemang.etal_2020}

\parencite{allemang.etal_2020}

\textcite{allemang.etal_2020} 

\end{document}
```

Output:

```
(Allemang et al., 2020)
(Allemang et al., 2020)
Allemang et al. (2020)
```

When adding a `maxcitenames=6` option we get the following which now shows all three authors in the first citation but does not abbreviate it to et al. in the second.

Output:

```
(Allemang, Hendler, & Gandon, 2020)
(Allemang, Hendler, & Gandon, 2020)
Allemang, Hendler, and Gandon (2020)
```

I am especially confused because [Basically the same question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248683/in-text-citation-with-biblatex-apa-not-using-et-al-correctly-two-authors-liste?newreg=4020c5c925104f36b60b9f4224a4c062) was asked back in 2015, and it apparently worked back then, according to the most upvoted answer. I know that they also included `uniquelist=true`, but that has not changed anything in my testing.

Please help me, as I am going insane...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of having up to six names on first citations and up to three + "et al." on subsequent citations is APA style according to the 6th edition of the APA manual. The guidance in the current 7th edition, however, is different (cf. https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/author-date). In 7th-edition APA style lists with three or more authors are always abbreviated to "`<first author>` + et al.". (There are exceptions in case the first authors are the same, but subsequent authors differ, but that is not relevant here.)

Current versions of [`biblatex-apa`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa) implement 7th-edition APA style and hence do not (generally) show more than two names on first citations. If you want 6th-edition APA style, use [`biblatex-apa6`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa6)'s `style=apa6,` instead of `style=apa,`.

Comment: You are my absolute savior!! I was actually thinking exactly this but googling for this didn't bring me to the right places.. I guess I am then just fine with using the default 7th-edition APA style. Incredible speed with the answer :)